# Prepare a Rails environment in a virtual machine with a single click

Tags: windows, scripting, vagrant, conemu

I am learning to develop Rails on Windows. As the Rails implementation is far from perfect on Windows, I use a virtual machine to launch the various Rails tools and servers, using Vagrant.

Each time I start my environment, I do the following :

- open 4 ConEmu Powershell tabs in my folder
- in the first tab, `subl .`, then `vagrant up` and wait for it to finish
- `vagrant ssh` (it uses the ssh client from my "Git for Windows" installation, I guess it's OpenSSH) in the first 3 tabs then `cd /vagrant` in each
- in the first tab, `rake db:migrate` then `rake test:prepare`
- in the first tab, `rails s` ; in the second tab, `guard -pc`
- the fourth tab is just left alone, it's used for git commands

Can you envision a script, or a series of scripts, that can launch all these commands ? I can think of a convoluted way of how to open the 4 tabs and launch the `vagrant ssh` (I didn't check if it worked yet), but I don't even know if it's possible to handle ssh sessions this way.

Comment: Don't know about "vagrant ssh", but I believe it can accept commands/script files. Also, you've not described what do you do in fourth tab.

Comment: You're right, I have added it. The first tab is the web server, the second the unit tests, in the the third I type my rails commands, and in the fourth, my git commands.

Comment: Btw, you have not mention in your Q "third tab".

Comment: Yes I have (third bullet point): I launch "vagrant ssh" in it, then "cd /vagrant", and then it's used for Rails commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your starting point. Create powershell script (`RunVG.ps1` for example)

```
Start-Process "vagrant" "up" -Wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process "vagrant" "ssh", "-new_console:s1THb" -Wait
Start-Process "vagrant" "ssh", "-new_console:s1TVb" -Wait
Start-Process "powershell" "-new_console:s2TVb"
& "vagrant" "ssh"
```

and run ConEmu with following command line (change path to `RunVG.ps1` accordingly)

```
ConEmu /cmd powershell -NoExit -Command "C:\Vagrant\RunVG.ps1"
```

After finishing script execution you will get connected ssh in first three tab and powershell in fourth tab. Actually, you'll get 2x2 splits, not tabs. If you don't need splits - use plain "-new_console".

Now, you need only pass additional arguments into your ssh instances for running commands in your tabs. Consult with ssh manual or competent users.

**UPD1**
Pasting into console example (this must be called from ConEmu's console)

```
conemuc /GUIMACRO Paste(2,"echo abc\necho def\n")
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll be sure to try it. Doesn't ConEmu supports "typing in the console", like "paste" seems to do ? That would be awesome for things like SSH commands.